# Content is not allowed in prolog with just created project

Tags: android

I have just created empty default project in Android Studio. When i try run it i get the error below:

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:_internal_aapt2_binary'.
> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:aapt2:4.1.0-6503028.
> Required by:
> project :app
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:aapt2:4.1.0-6503028.
> > Could not parse POM https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/4.1.0-6503028/aapt2-4.1.0-6503028.pom
> > Content is not allowed in prolog.

How can i resolve it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just do the following:

1. update the android gradle plugin to the latest version.
2. restart the project.
3. build and run.
4. don't forget to add `google()` in allprojects -> repositories (as showing in the image below)

.. solved :)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvXid.png)

Comment: please check the updated comment, and refer to https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin for more info.

Comment: I`ve set gradle version to 4.0.0 and it works, click update and the same error